# How to perform matching between two sequences?

Tags: cntk

I have two mini-batch of sequences :

```
a = C.sequence.input_variable((10))
b = C.sequence.input_variable((10))
```

Both `a` and `b` have variable-length sequences.
I want to do matching between them where matching is defined as: match (eg. dot product) token at each time step of `a` with token at every time step of `b` .

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

I have mostly answered this [on github](https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/issues/2217) but to be consistent with SO rules, I am including a response here. In case of something simple like a dot product you can take advantage of the fact that it factorizes nicely, so the following code works

```
axisa = C.Axis.new_unique_dynamic_axis('a')
axisb = C.Axis.new_unique_dynamic_axis('b')
a = C.sequence.input_variable(1, sequence_axis=axisa)
b = C.sequence.input_variable(1, sequence_axis=axisb)
c = C.sequence.broadcast_as(C.sequence.reduce_sum(a), b) * b
c.eval({a: [[1, 2, 3],[4, 5]], b: [[6, 7], [8]]})
[array([[ 36.],
       [ 42.]], dtype=float32), array([[ 72.]], dtype=float32)]
```

In the general case you need the following steps

```
static_b, mask = C.sequence.unpack(b, neutral_value).outputs
scores = your_score(a, static_b)
```

The first line will convert the `b` sequence into a static tensor with one more axis than `b`. Because of packing, some elements of this tensor will be invalid and those will be indicated by the `mask`. The `neutral_value` will be placed as a dummy value in the static_b tensor wherever data was missing. Depending on your score you might be able to arrange for the `neutral_value` to not affect the final score (e.g. if your score is a dot product a 0 would be a good choice, if it involves a softmax -infinity or something close to that would be a good choice). The second line can now have access to each element of `a` and all the elements of `b` as the first axis of `static_b`. For a dot product `static_b` is a matrix and one element of `a` is a vector so a matrix vector multiplication will result in a sequence whose elements are all inner products between the corresponding element of a and all elements of `b`.